# How to script for postman like API in cypress

Tags: api, cypress

I am new in Cypress,
I wanted to create my first code for API in cypress.

Here is the details

```
POST
https://www.mywebsite.com/myproject/get-customer-login-url


HEADER
------
KEY: token 
VALUE: HKt7854UHTFGR78#78
DESCRIPTION: 

KEY: Content-Type
VALUE: application/json
DESCRIPTION: 

BODY
-----
RAW: 
{ 
   "customerid": "54607"
}
```

Using above parameters, I got below result and status in Postman.

```
RESULT:
"{\"url\":\"default.aspx?rootid=843&companyId=54607&eccuserid=0&isloginspecialrole=False&userid=e91zNO%2bBBCI%3d&t=view\",\"code\":\"1\"}"

STATUS"
200 OK
```

I need to made script for cypress using these POST URL and parameters/key.
And want response like

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/myproject/default.aspx?rootid=843&companyId=54607&eccuserid=0&isloginspecialrole=False&userid=e91zNO%2bBBCI%3d&t=view
```

can anyone help me out to my cypress script?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example, you might have to adjust it. This example just validates that status of the response is 200 but you can validate response contents as well. Refer cypress docs for details:

```
describe('Test the api', function() {
it ('status should be 200', () => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'your-url',
        followRedirect: false,
        headers: {
            'token': 'HKt7854UHTFGR78#78',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: {"customerid": "54607"},
    })
      .then((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200)
      })
    })
})
```